# Reading files from android application

Tags: android, performance, file, io, android-ndk

I have 9000 files in the memory card, I have created an application that read each file and parse it in to a String and put that String in a HashMap in order to avoid repetition,and save the names of only unrepeated files, but that operation is taking about 7 to 10 seconds.. is there any way to make that faster.. I tried to find better method but I didn't find anything...
Object : get the names and Strings of all the unrepeated files..
Is there any way to do that faster using java, new IO, or NDK, is it worth to install NDK and try that using C language and pointers..
I appreciate any help..

Answer (score 0):

Its obviously that even just loading of 9k files takes some time. Imagine there a lot of android devices and there are many devices which are not as fast as device which you are using to test. So the operation gonna take even more time on such devices. The problem is a numerous of small files. Maybe you should pack it in one, lets say a JSON or XML? Reading of 1 file is more faster and reliable.